# Generating a number once a day for all users in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm relatively new to JavaScript, and I'm looking to create something like a Wordle clone. Like Wordle, I want to generate a new word each day for all users. I've seen solutions with a random number generator that stores the number in localstorage. However, wouldn't this mean each user who goes on the website would have a different number? Is there a simple way to generate the same number for all users on a site?

Comment: You'd have 2 solutions: a) have server-based storage and b) formula that would generate word based on date.

Comment: Ah, I assumed that would be the two possibilities. Do you have any recommendations for tutorials for the first solution? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if there is a "simple way". if you are building this Javascript inside your html files, then it's executed by the browser, that is, client side. Then, each user will have its own execution result. In order to do what you want you'll need to build a backend application (server side). In this case, the server would process your algorithm for all users, and the javascript would just communicate with that server (it's not that simple for someone new to javascript). Or, you can request to a public API that generates a single number daily. But I don't know any API like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own pseudo random generator, these aren’t actually random but they generate numbers based on a seed (which will be the date)

```
// Get the day of the month with Date object
const day = new Date().getDate();

// And the month to prevent repeats
const month = new Date().getMonth();
```

Then you can create your function.

 
To make it seem even more random, you can get the middle numbers and use those.

```
function random(){
   // Crazy math stuff
   let num = Math.round((day+4) / month * 39163).toString();

   // To convert it back to a number, use the + operator before parentheses
   // Don’t forget to use % on the max value, I just put 31 as a placeholder
   return +(num[2] + num[3]) % 31;
}
```

This can be changed to fit your needs ^

This will be the same for every user for the entire day since it is pseudo random and based on a seed

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage is a browser feature, It exists only in the client.

You Will need to persist the data somewhere, a database (MySQL, postgres, etc..) or in a file

The easiest way is in a file, you can search Google "save data to file node.js"